# For Embarcadero C++ builder where do I find send and receive email?

Tags: c++, email

For Embarcadero C++ builder 10.2 where do I find send and receive email modules?

I do not see these in my tools palette so assume they have to be imported from somewhere.  Is this correct and if so from where?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  In my Embacadero 10.2 Professional C++ Tools Palette I do not see an entry for email.  How can I get such an entry and so extract the send/receive email components.  If they are not in the tools palette, where can I find TSendEmail, for example.  Thanks.